# Python: Pulling data as variables from a csv and inserting into a basic file (NAPALM configs)

Tags: python, csv

Problem:  I am trying to mass code some network devices with NAPALM using a base template that has variable information for each device. The current coding does not scale well, in particular, the assignment of variables from the .csv and the replacement of text with said variables in the config file are the sections that seem needlessly huge when I start looking at 10+ variables. e.g. (variable = row['column name']) and (data = data.replace('{variable}', variable))

Auto-generating the base variables from each column in the .csv is escaping me completely. Having a few variables that are combos of the generated variables seems ok. For the replacement section, I have thought about placing the variables in a list and iterating over the list as the names are the same, but couldn't figure out a way besides manually coding the list.

I chose to go with pandas vs csv as I liked how clean and concise the coding seemed to be. I also did some tests with pulling the data from the csv and writing some 20 or so rows a thousand times for comparison between them and saw about 2 seconds difference between the two methods. I don't see ever pushing new configs to more than 25-50 devices at a time, the read/write of a dataframe vs csv would be negligible, but I could be mistaken.

=========================================================================

For reference NAPALM reads configurations from files in the following way:

```
driver = get_network_driver("ios")
with driver(IP, Username, Password) as device:
   device.load_merge_candidate(filename='Config.cfg')
```

The Config.cfg file is just a file loaded with ios commands, but to program multiple devices, I was looking at looping through a .csv file filled with the variable needed to replace in the config file.

***Base Configuration File Example***

*Base_Config.cfg*

```
hostname {hostname}
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
udld enable
interface vlan {managementVLAN}
ip address {managementIP} {managementSubnet}
```

***.csv Example File***

*ios_switch_info.csv*

```
Temp IP,Building,Room,Device Role,Management IP,Management Subnet
192.168.1.1,Main,001,Access,10.1.1.2,255.255.255.0
192.168.1.2,Main,101,Access,10.1.1.3,255.255.255.0
192.168.1.3,Branch,007,Access,10.1.2.2,255.255.255.0
```

***Temp Configuration File Example***

*Temp.cfg*

```
hostname MainAcc001
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
udld enable
interface vlan 101
ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
```

***Script Example***

*Base_IOS_Config.py*

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from getpass import getpass
from napalm import get_network_driver

username = input("Username: ")
password = getpass()
driver = get_network_driver("ios")
df = pd.read_csv('ios_switch_info.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    # This section of variable assignment could get very long  
  
    tempIP = row['Temp IP']
    building = row['Building']
    room = row['Room']
    deviceRole= row['Device Role']
    managementIP = row['Management IP']
    managementSubnet= row['Management Subnet']
    hostname = row['Building'] + row['Device Role'][:3] + row['Room']
    managementVLAN = int(managementIP.split('.')[2]) + 100
    
    with open('Base_Config.cfg', 'r') as base_config:
        data = base_config.read()

    # This section of replacement could get very long depending on number of variables 

    data = data.replace('{hostname}', hostname)
    data = data.replace('{managementIP}', managementIP)
    data = data.replace('{managementSubnet}', managementSubnet)
    data = data.replace('{managementVLAN}', managementVLAN)

    with open('Temp.cfg', 'w') as temp_config:
        temp_config.write(data)

    with driver(tempIP,username,password) as device:
        print(f"Accessing {hostname}")
        device.load_merge_candidate(filename='Temp.cfg')
        ........other stuff..........
    device.close()
os.remove('Temp.cfg')
```

Comment: I think your question is "how can I be lazier/more efficient?" If that's the case, the mapping appears to be tailored to both the CSV fields and the desired output config fields. That's the manual process I think you're looking to refine?

Comment: Pretty much on the lazier/more efficient description. I ended up figuring out that I could pull all the .csv variables with a (row.to_dict()) to replace all the explicit naming of each variable. Then I found out that you could call in **globals() to get the import credential variables into the system.

Comment: If you were able to find a solution, I suggest posting your solution as an answer so that other folks who stumble onto this post can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up coming up with for the assignment of variables from the .csv (switch specific variables) and the import ios_creds * (variables across multiple switches e.g. NTP server address) instead of manually assigning them:

```
device_info = row.to_dict() # creates dict of .csv variables {column:variable}
device_info.update(**globals) # adds all global variables to dict
```

for putting said variables into the config file, instead of replacing each variable line by line with data.replace, I ended up using the following:

```
for key, value in device_info.items():
    data = data.replace("{" + str(key) + "}", str(value))
```

This parses the config file looking for a variable (e.g. {Hostname}) and replaces it with the corresponding variable that was saved in the dictionary (e.g. Hostname:MainAcc001)